# How do I know if the user clicks the "back" button?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm using anchors for dealing with unique urls for an ajaxy website. However, I want to reload the content when the user hits the Browser's "back" button so the contents always matches the url.

How can I achieve this? Is there a jQuery event triggering when user clicks "Back"?

Comment: In short, you can't reliably detect if the back button was clicked cross browser.

Comment: @Russ: You can catch back-button presses quite reliably in most (if not all) significant browsers.

Comment: @Russ, type some text in the answer (not comment) box below, and try to hit back.

Comment: @Kirk - That's not *just* the back button, that's leaving the page in any manner, clicking a link, closing the browser, etc.

Comment: @Kirk - Ah, but that's onbeforeunload event, which won't distinguish the back button press specifically

Comment: @Russ: Storing some state (a running index will do) in the hash portion of the URL allows you to detect when the user has gone back in history, which is equivalent enough to a "back button press". Usually when people talk about "detecting the back button" they usually mean detecting any navigation, though.

Comment: @Matti - that's a very narrow scope for your example...your original statement is a broad one, for example if I load `page1.html` go to `page2.html`...you can't detect that it was specifically the back button when i'm clicking back from `page2` to `page1`.

Comment: @Nick: But if I use a running index in the hash of the page, I can reliably enough detect normal people navigating back and forth. Of course if there's a Nick Craver editing my URLs or something, it might not work, but that'll probably be a largely insignificant portion of my users.

Comment: @Matti - My point was you're talking about a **hash change**, specifically, plenty of sites are just `page1`, `page2`, etc with no hash ever coming into play...in all of those cases you can't distinguish a back button click from a browser closing, etc.

Comment: @Nick: OP specified anchors (presumably hashes).

Comment: @Matti - Again that's my point, *presumably* (an assumption :), in this case yes, *if* you're going back on a hash...if you're back to where the page started you're in the same boat of not being able to identify the back button was pressed.  Even in this example speaking purely on hashes, you can't distinguish the back from the forward button, not in every case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a hashchange event.  There are a couple of popular plugins.  I've been using the address plugin and like it.  Some will suggest BBQ also.

[Address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/)

[jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ajax urls and not reloading the page, I'm guessing you have `#something` style URLs, using hash navigation.  If that's the case you probably want the [`window.onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) event to reload the appropriate content.

Since it's not supported by *all* browsers, [there's a plugin for this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange), your code would look something like this:

```
$(window).hashchange(function() {
  //do something with location.hash that just changed
});
```

Answer (score 0):

YUI history manager does this by checking the hash every 10ms using setInterval.  There is no event registered by back, so that is probably the only way possible.

Comment: The event exists in some browsers, it's best to use it where it exists and poll when it doesn't, the plugin in my answer does exactly this.